# Nostalgic expressive word

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word that means, "I was there" that also expresses feelings of nostalgia.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence indicating the location you would like to place the word?

Comment: Without an example sentence, the best I can suggest is "I was there...~sigh!"

Comment: I think you would really need to find a more conrete example

Answer (score 2):

The word *reminisce* comes to mind. It means to remember or write about things from the past according to the Encarda dictionary. Nevertheless, I believe that its usage also includes a feeling of recalling memories with fondness.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is to ***[relive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relive)***. No nostalgia or longing though.

> Live through (an experience or feeling, especially an unpleasant one) again in one’s imagination or memory:
>   he broke down sobbing as he relived the attack
>
> OD

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of "déjà vu"?

> **déjà vu**
>
> *noun*
>
> the illusion of having previously experienced something actually being encountered for the first time

*Source: Dictionary.com*